# Can't see login in the routes, how to add other actions to a login process in Laravel 5.6 clone of jeremykenedy/laravel-auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I cloned https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth to learn Laravel from scratch as I go with Laravel 5.6 and the aforementioned project, as there's a lot of concepts new to me and I learn best when doing.

I have watched some Laracasts and read docs and I get now is "time to read some documentation", but not all documentation and tutorials work for everyone, and I'm not finding I've broken the back of my understanding yet.

I can't see login in the routes folder. I was expecting to see it in the web.php file. I can see logout. Why is this? Where is this :| ?

I'm trying to hook on an action to the login process that logs in to a web app, and was hoping to debug what was occuring etc. to compliment my learning.

If I'm going about this in the wrong way, do please point that out!

Comment: In the web.php file there is : `// Authentication Routes Auth::routes();` which generates all login routes. Login controller by defauld and in this case is `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`

Comment: I can't see any actual "login" route in [the file](https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php) though.

Was it created with the `php artisan migrate` command?

Comment: It is handled in the trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`